# I have a mistake in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Index.cshtml

```
@using eCommerceStatic.Models;
@model IEnumerable<ProductModel>

@{
//ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-example-1z" class="carousel slide carousel-fade pt-4" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!--First slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="view" style="background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/8-col/img%282%29.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
                <div class="mask rgba-black-strong d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">
                        <h1 class="mb-4">
                            <strong>Learn Bootstrap 4 with MDB</strong>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Best & free guide of responsive web design</strong>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">
                            <strong>
                                The most comprehensive tutorial for the Bootstrap 4. Loved by over 500 000 users. Video and
                                written versions
                                available. Create your own, stunning website.
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-lg">
                            Start
                            free tutorial
                            <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap ml-2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Content -->
                </div>
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/First slide-->
        <!--Second slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="view" style="background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/8-col/img%283%29.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
                <div class="mask rgba-black-strong d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">
                        <h1 class="mb-4">
                            <strong>Learn Bootstrap 4 with MDB</strong>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Best & free guide of responsive web design</strong>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">
                            <strong>
                                The most comprehensive tutorial for the Bootstrap 4. Loved by over 500 000 users. Video and
                                written versions
                                available. Create your own, stunning website.
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-lg">
                            Start
                            free tutorial
                            <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap ml-2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Content -->
                </div>
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/Second slide-->
        <!--Third slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="view" style="background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/8-col/img%285%29.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
                <div class="mask rgba-black-strong d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">
                        <h1 class="mb-4">
                            <strong>Learn Bootstrap 4 with MDB</strong>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Best & free guide of responsive web design</strong>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">
                            <strong>
                                The most comprehensive tutorial for the Bootstrap 4. Loved by over 500 000 users. Video and
                                written versions
                                available. Create your own, stunning website.
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-lg">
                            Start
                            free tutorial
                            <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap ml-2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Content -->
                </div>
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/Third slide-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
</div>

<!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
<!--Main layout-->

@Html.Partial("_GetCategories")
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <!--Navbar-->

        <!--/.Navbar-->
        @Html.Partial("_ProductList",Model)
    </div>
</main>
<!--Main layout-->
```

HomeController.cs

```
  public PartialViewResult _GetCategories()
        {
            return PartialView(_context.Categories.ToList());
        }
```

_GetCategories.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<eCommerceStatic.Entity.Category>
 eCommerceStatic.Entity
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mdb-color lighten-3 mt-3 mb-5">
    <!-- Navbar brand -->
    <span class="navbar-brand">Kategoriler :</span>
    <!-- Collapse button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#basicExampleNav"
            aria-controls="basicExampleNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Collapsible content -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="basicExampleNav">
        <!-- Links -->
        @foreach (var category in Model)
        {
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/List/@category.Id">@category.Name</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        <!-- Links -->
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="md-form my-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Collapsible content -->
</nav>
```

Error

> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[eCommerceStatic.Models.ProductModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[eCommerceStatic.Entity.Category]'

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error sounds pretty clear to me...you're passing the wrong type. You're giving it a collection of ProductModel but you need to give it a collection of Category. Either change it to pass a Category, or change the other side to expect a ProductModel.

Comment: what should I add to which page?

Comment: Hello @developer , you have to check your own question, there is an answer below which I spent time to write and I know that it is the correct answer because I've checked already 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

It is because, your **Partial View** which is:

`_GetCategories.cshtml` requires `@model IEnumerable<eCommerceStatic.Entity.Category>`

but your `Index.cshtml` which is your **Main View** in this case, requires 
`@model IEnumerable<ProductModel>`

So, you should be using `@model IEnumerable<ProductModel>` in your `_GetCategories.cshtml`

In these cases, consider using a common model class. You can do something similar to this:

Create a new **Model class**,

Create `List<ProductModel>` and `List<Category>` properties.

```
public class ProductsAndCategories
{
    public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

So in your `Index` :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
      var model = new ProductsAndCategories
      {
           //Define your IEnumerable<ProductModel>
           //Below is an example...
           Products = _context.ProductModel.ToList()
      };
      return View(model);
}
```

And in your `_GetCategories` :

```
 public PartialViewResult _GetCategories()
{
      var model = new ProductsAndCategories
      {
           Categories = _context.Categories.ToList()
      };
      return PartialView(model);
}
```

**CSHTML**

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@model ProductsAndCategories
```

and in your `_GetCategories.cshtml`:

```
@model ProductsAndCategories
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mdb-color lighten-3 mt-3 mb-5">
    <!-- Navbar brand -->
    ....
```